# Run python GUI (w/PySide2) on RPi startup before loading desktop

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pyside, pyside2, raspberry-pi-zero

I'm trying to run a PySide GUI just after the bootup of my RPi zero W. I've found there are many methods to do so, but I've not been able to make them work as desired.
To put a brief context, I would want to:

1. Put an image at the splash screen (already acheived following: https://www.tomshardware.com/how-to/custom-raspberry-pi-splash-screen).
2. When the splash screen turns off, I would like the PySide2 GUI to pop up (without desktop or anything else).

I've acheived to boot up with the comand line in "quiet" mode, so the user does not see which services are running or whatever is happening, also changing the splash image and running the code of the PySide GUI automatically on bootup following the "autostart" method described here: https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/how-to-run-a-raspberry-pi-program-on-startup/all. Note: I've read that with this method the GUI runs AFTER the desktop is loaded, but I have not been able to make any other method work.

So, let's say that I have the GUI code in a file called GUI.py inside the /home/pi folder. Does anyone now how It can be acheived to make it run before the desktop, right after the splash screen?

Thank you in advanced,

I've tried what's described in this video, but it does not work for me:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m3rfls00OtY

Comment: What do you mean by "before loading the desktop"? Are you referring to the window manager? If that's the case, it's almost impossible (if not by extremely modifying the system configuration): Qt, as most UI toolkits, requires a window manager to show the GUI.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the response. I mean that I would like the application GUI to appear on the screen without the necessity to load the desktop (or to appear before the desktop). What happens is that the RPi boots up, the desktop background image appears and after that, the PySide GUI that I created and runs with the "autostart" method. I would like to acheive something like the video in the last link: When booting up, it appears the splash image on the screen and right after that, the GUI itself.
Another way to say it: Opening the GUI automatically from the console; suppose it makes sense.

Comment: Then you should probably do what explained in that video. For that, you'll need to ensure that the login session is auto started with a valid user, which will then start up the X server and finally your application.

Comment: Sure, I did what was on the video, but it did not work for me. Maybe because it is another RPi model, I'm not sure. I am asking for another method in case anyone knows it, or the same method but adapted to a RPi zero W.

Comment: "It did not work" is quite vague. **What** part does not work? We cannot just guess things, we need *context*.

Comment: So.. following the method on the video, the splash screen image changes, the RPi boots up, but it opens the desktop without opening my PySide GUI before neither after it. So I suppose that the issue is at the "autostart" process of my application. I suppose I should do something different from including "sudo - pi -c /home/pi.." before "exit 0" at the rc.local file.

Comment: The most important thing is that you have to *wait* for the X server to be active. I'm not familiar with RP nor its distros, you'll have to check for their documentation in order to find how to properly run UI programs on startup.